# Compustat data access: C++ or SAS

Tags: c++, sas

I will soon be accessing a lot of market data from Compustat.  Can anyone point to specifications for programmatic access to Compustat data?  I have heard Compustat has bindings for SAS, but would rather use C++.  Anybody have any info?

Answer (score 0):

SAS ETS provides libraries for accessing the data directly.  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/66100/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_sasexccm_overview.htm

It depends on what you are looking to do.  We use CRSP/Compustat data at work primarily with SAS.  We have more analysts types and less programmer types.